Derived class does not see base class functions
I have a base class define a polymorphic function with different footprint
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}

    virtual int& SetValue(int& v) {return v;}
    virtual double& SetValue(double& v) {return v;}
};

Its first child derives a variant of the polymorphic function for type double
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1() : Base() {}

    double& SetValue(double& v) override {return v;}
};

The second child calls the first version for type int
class Derived2 : public Derived1
{
public:
    Derived2() : Derived1() {}

    void DoSomething()
    {
        int i;
        this->SetValue(i); // compilation error
    }
};

Theoretically, it should be possible since the int version is already defined in Base, but I got the compilation error
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘double&’ to a value of type ‘int’

What could I do to fix this other than creating a new derived function in Derived1, which just calls the same function in Base anyway?

using Base::SetValue;

The Derived1 class will hide the functions from the Base class. To be sure to get the functions from the base class you can do this->Base::SetValue(i)

Also please note that the code is valid (once the problem about hiding is solved), but only very narrowly. The variable i is uninitialized, and will have an indeterminate value. If that value is used anywhere (which fortunately it isn't in the shown code) it would lead to undefined behavior.

Theoretically... name lookup happens before overload resolution.

Overloading occurs among functions defined in the same scope. There is only one version of SetValue defined in Derived1, so that's the one that gets selected in Derived2. (You'd have the same problem if DoSomething was a member of Derived1; Derived2 is a distraction here)
